# Asm Console Input/Output

Tags: assembly, io, console

I am trying to make a basic 'game' (input/output) in the console with assembly. As I am new to assembly, I am not too sure of how things work in lower level languages: I am used to the C++ / C# environment.

What I am trying to achieve is that the user types in their name, and the console outputs whether it is the same as the variable myName or not. If I have made mistakes in my code I would be very grateful if you could correct them

```
.text
.global main

main:
myName db "Name"
call readline 
cmp myName, ebx
je same
jne notsame

same:
mov eax, "We have the same name"
jmp print

notsame:
mov eax, "We have different names"
jmp print

readline:
; read console line
mov ebx, line ; line is whatever the input is
ret

print:
; do something with eax
```

**EDIT: Would this be any better?**

```
.text
.global main

main:
myName db "Name"
call readline 
pop ebx
cmp myName, ebx
je same
jne notsame

same:
push "We have the same name"
jmp print

notsame:
push "We have different names"
jmp print

readline:
; read console line
push line ; line is whatever the input is
ret

print:
pop eax
; do something with eax
```

Comment: Looks like x86/x86-64 code. The code is probably invalid as `main:` starts with `db "Name"` (`db 0x4e 0x61 0x6d 0x65`), which is in 32-bit code (`echo -n 'Name' | udcli -32`) `dec esi; popad; insd; gs:`, and in 64-bit code: (`echo -n 'Name' | udcli -64`) `invalid; insd; gs:`. So if it's x86-64 code, it crashes immediately, if it's 32-bit protected mode OS userland code, it probably does not have priviledges to execute `insd`. Anyway, what you ask can be googled, and anyway it's hard to help you without knowing which OS and which assembler.

Comment: It's 32-bit: "eax", not "rax", but which assembler, and which system - if any: Windows? Linux? I'd guess Windows (not AT&T syntax).

Comment: Using `eax` doesn't imply 32-bit code, it works fine in x86-64 code too. Using a 32-bit register as a dest in x86-64 code zeroes the top 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register. `mov eax, "We have the same name"` is invalid code, as the size of `"We have the same name"` is 21 bytes or 168 bits and thus won't fit in any 32-bit/64-bit register. I see no other reason to use AT&T syntax except that 1. I'm not sure if all the functionality of GCC extended assembly is available using Intel syntax, and 2. legacy code. I see no reason to use AT&T syntax in any other Linux x86/x86-64 assembler.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?

The code is all kinds of off. First, console input is not a scalar - it's a text string. That is, an arbitrary set of characters. You can't expect it to fit into a single register. You need to declare a buffer and pass it to the console reading routine so that the characters are placed there. Second, to compare strings, you need to do that character by character - strings are not integers. So, a loop would be necessary. Read up on those.

Third, you really need to tell everyone what's your operating system. The specifics of console I/O would depend on that. On Linux, it's syscalls. On Windows, it's Win32 API.

Comment: Then GetStdHandle() then ReadConsole(). Are you familiar with Win32 API? Are you familiar with calling it from assembly?

Comment: Sorry, no, how would I do that?

Comment: If it isn't homework, why are you writing in assembly to begin with? This kind of program is much easier to write in C++ or C#.

Comment: I am trying assembly out

Comment: Then you're doing it all wrong. StackOverflow is not a learning resource. If we write your code for you, where's the learning in that? Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).